# How to inherit from another model in a view in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask with SQLAlchemy and I have a "user" DB.Model class. I have a view in my database that essentially does a SELECT * FROM user WHERE ..., and I'd like to be able to treat that view like my User model.

Is it possible to inherit all the methods and properties from my User class in a new class that reads from my view?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you want to use seems like an example of a single table inheritance mapping. Here's the [SQL Alchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance) doc about it.

So in your class declaration for the `user` table you can specify `mapper_args` as:

```
__mapper_args__ = {
    'polymorphic_on':<column used in your where clause>,
    'polymorphic_identity':'user'
}
```

You will have to declare the view class in a way similar to:

```
class UserView(User):
   __mapper_args__ = {
      'polymorphic_identity':'userview'
   }
```

Comment: If I'm reading the documentation correctly, I think this will query from the same table as user, rather than the view?